# sourceid ignored on search REST call (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, search, rest

When I submit a search REST call, I am providing the sourceid of the list I want to search (an asset library).  The results returned from the query are not limited to the items in the list, rather they appear to be all lists across the entire SharePoint site.

Here is the query I am using:

```
http://site/teams/me/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='c10ebb71-4b3d-415b-a457-a9bac5edf0f9'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Source ID looks to be the GUID of search scopes. It looks like you want to use ListId: instead. [Source](http://www.onemenny.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-search-service/)

> LIST Search (document library)
>
> ```
> https://myhost.com/rnd/mennysite1/_api/search/query?querytext='horses+AND+ListId:4f87042a-22cb-4c45-b043-972bd1b414b7'&clienttype='Custom'
> ```
>
> Things to notice:
>   Notice the listId property is using “:” (contains)
>   and not equals. For some strange reason this is how it works, the
>   equals returns nothing

Comment: I marked this as an answer - I will upvote when I have enough reputation points.  Thanks again.